# Save attachments for certain date

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I am trying to save all attachemnts from emails that arrived today.

I do not know how to reference the date property of an email object.

My existing code:

```vb
Sub GetAllAttachments() 'Exports and saves all attachements in the inbox
    
    Dim ns As NameSpace
    Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim Atmt As Attachment
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim i As Integer
    
    Today = Format(Now(), "yyyy MM dd")
    
    Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = ns.Folders("Secondary")
    Set Inbox = Inbox.Folders("Inbox")
    
    i = 0
    
    If Inbox.Items.Count = 0 Then
       MsgBox "There are no messages in the Inbox.", vbInformation, _
              "Nothing Found"
       Exit Sub
    End If
    
    For Each Item In Inbox.Items
        If EMAIL_DATE = Today Then
            For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
                FileName = "C:\Email Attachments\" & Atmt.FileName
                Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next Atmt
    Next Item
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Item doesn't have the date property.

Try using the

```
 Outlook.MailItem
```

For example:

```
 Dim oMI as Outlook.MailItem

 For Each oMI in Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
     Msgbox (oMI.RecievedTime)
 Next
```

You will need to strip the date from the time.

Comment: It keeps complaining that the object doesnt support this method.

Comment: Given "Dim oMI as Outlook.MailItem" you must only select mailitems.

Comment: Are you trying to save attachments just from emails or do you need to save the attachments of meetings also?

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant

Sub GetAllAttachments()

'Exports and saves all attachements in the inbox

Dim ns As namespace

Dim mailBox As folder
Dim myInbox As folder

Dim myItem As Object
Dim myItems As Items

Dim Atmt As Attachment
Dim FileName As String

Dim today As Date

today = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd")
Debug.Print
Debug.Print Format(today, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss AM/PM"), "midnight"

Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set mailBox = ns.folders("Secondary")
Set myInbox = mailBox.folders("Inbox")

Set myItems = myInbox.Items

If myItems.Count = 0 Then
   MsgBox "There are no messages in the Inbox.", vbInformation, _
          "Nothing Found"
   Exit Sub
End If

myItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True

For Each myItem In myItems
    
    If myItem.Class = olMail Then
    
        If myItem.ReceivedTime > today Then
        
            Debug.Print myItem.ReceivedTime, myItem.subject
            
            For Each Atmt In myItem.Attachments
                FileName = "C:\Email Attachments\" & Atmt.FileName
                Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
            Next Atmt
            
        Else
        
            Debug.Print
            Debug.Print myItem.ReceivedTime, "** Exiting - prior to today **"
            Exit For
            
        End If
        
    Else
        ' Mailitem properties may not apply
        Debug.Print "Not a mailitem."
        
    End If
    
Next myItem

End Sub
```

Reference material for the Outlook object model.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/outlook/object-model

MailItem.ReceivedTime Property:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem